# Como formatar titulo para formato de url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

Por exemplo, tenho um título : 'Teste Titulo Url'.
Mas preciso deixar ele em formato de url, existe alguma função que faça isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe sim, use `strtolower`e `url_title`.

**strtolower** : Retorna string com todos os caracteres convertidos para minúsculos.

**url_title** : Pega uma string como entrada e cria uma seqüência de URL amigável.

**Exemplo** :

```
$title = 'Teste titulo Url';

$title_url = strtolower(url_title($title));
```

Retorna : `teste-titulo-url`.

Ps: `url_title` faz parte do `URL Helper` do CodeIgniter, que deve ser carregado utilizando :

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Ps: Sei muito de programação (ainda estou naquela difícil fase de aprendizado) essa foi uma das únicas perguntas que por acaso sei a solução por ter passado pelo mesmo problema, mas se tiver algo errado fico aberto para melhorar a resposta. ;)

Comment: Só acho que faltou um "pouco" ali na 1a frase ein

Comment: @AndreyHartung Faltou mesmo hahaha,nem tinha notado! Agora não tem como editar mais! De qualquer forma obrigado! ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Existe sim, use `strtolower`e `url_title`.
>
> **strtolower** : Retorna string com todos os caracteres convertidos para minúsculos.
>
> **url_title** : Pega uma string como entrada e cria uma seqüência de URL amigável.
>
> **Exemplo** :
>
> ```
> $title = 'Teste titulo Url';
>
> $title_url = strtolower(url_title($title));
> ```
>
> Retorna : `teste-titulo-url`.
>
> Ps: `url_title` faz parte do `URL Helper` do CodeIgniter, que deve ser
>   carregado utilizando :
>
> ```
> $this->load->helper('url');
> ```

@GWER esqueceu de citar que existem poucos acentos no inglês com isso essa função exclui as letras com acentos, crie uma função antes de utilizar a `url_title()` para substituir os caracteres especias da url, por exemplo:

```
//remove acentos e caracteres especiais de uma string
function remove_acentos($string = NULL){
    $procurar   = array('À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì','Í','Î','Ï','Ð','Ñ','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ø','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','ß','à','á','â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ñ','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ÿ');
    $substituir = array('A','A','A','A','A','A','AE','C','E','E','E','E','I','I','I','I','D','N','O','O','O','O','O','O','U','U','U','U','Y','s','a','a','a','a','a','a','ae','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','n','o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y');
    return str_replace($procurar, $substituir, $string);

}

//função que gera um slug com base no título
function slug($string = NULL){
    $string = remove_acentos($string);
    return url_title($string, '-', TRUE);//função do helper url | url_title(DA_ONDE_PEGA_OS_DADOS, O SEPARADOR ENTRE AS PALAVRAS, BOOLEAN TUDO MINUSCULO OU NÃO)
}
```

Comment: Não me lembrava da função `url_title()`; vai ser uma mão na roda agora, mas complementando: Há acentos em inglês (em poucas palavras, mas tem) e no helper `Text` do CI, tem exatamente essa função para remoção de acentuação: `convert_accented_characters()`

Comment: vlw @JhonatanOliveira, já concertei minha burrada

Comment: De boa fera!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
    public function url_maker($string = NULL){
    $procurar   = array('À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì','Í',
        'Î','Ï','Ð','Ñ','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ø','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','ß','à','á',
        'â','ã','ä','å','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ñ','ò','ó','ô',
        'õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ÿ','}',']','°', '+', '(',')','*','#','@','!','#','$','%','¨',':','’','‘',',');
   $substituir = array('A','A','A','A','A','A','AE','C','E','E','E','E','I','I',
       'I','I','D','N','O','O','O','O','O','O','U','U','U','U','Y','s','a','a',
       'a','a','a','a','ae','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','n','o','o','o',
       'o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','','','',' ');
    $replace = str_replace($procurar, $substituir, $string);
    $replace = str_replace(' ', '-', $replace);
    $replace = str_replace(array('-----', '----', '---', '--'), '-', $replace);
    return $replace;

}

$Name = "gabriel ariza ---gomes de castro ! teste } ] é usuário do SOpt";

        echo "<a href='".$this->url_maker($Name)."'>".$Name."</a>";
```

Comment: Adicione alguma informação a esta resposta